Determine the amount of NVME clusters allocated for a sparse file including inode
Linux file systems can support arbitrary sparse ranges within a file. To do so, it must obviously be keeping track of the ranges that are active. Is there a way to determine how much actual space on disk that tracking is taking up? I believe stat only returns the amount of space allocated to the file contents itself, not including the space required for book keeping of the file.
A related question is whether stat can be used to determine the size of bookkeeping data to keep track of the children files?
The thing I’m trying to accomplish is compare two ways of storing data & see which one is actually cheaper once you account for all extra book keeping that the OS hides under the hood.
